# Excel hh:mm:ss format not recognized

Tags: excel

so I got a problem in Excel with this format.
This one

```
1402:18:02
```

is recognized correctly and I see

```
27.02.1900  10:18:02
```

behind.
But for some reason this one

```
13355:51:33
```

and this

```
12450:35:36
```

is not getting recognized.
Same custom format [hh]:mm:ss is used for all cells.

[image]

I have ran out of ideas and have no idea of what to do and how to fix this.

Comment: You have to apply the format [hh]:mm:ss to the cell **before** entering the contents to avoid excel guessing them, so then you can input your values and have excel correctly interpret them and show them with your desired format.  Note that further edits of the content will transform momentarily the input into date and time, but get formated to [hh]:mm:ss once entered.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that was a some type of bug / lag with Excel. Now it works.